# Erro de parse ao enviar imagens pelo axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, watson

Estou tentando enviar imagens via método POST no axios, porém quando executo o script, ele me da esse erro:

```
  error:
       { code: 500,
         error_id: 'server_error',
         description: 'Error parsing request into form data' } } }
```

***Meu script***

```
var app = require('express')();

var fs = require('fs');
var axios = require('axios');


var param = { 
    images_file: fs.createReadStream( __dirname + '/robot_orthographic.jpg')
}

axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?version=2018-03-19',
    param,
    config: { 
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    },
    auth: {
        username: 'apiKey',
        password: 'KEY'
    }
}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('servidor rodando!');
});
```

Já tentei usar a lib `form-data` porém continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: Está enviando um json + um arquivo?

Comment: @marconi uma imagem para ser mais específico

Comment: Já tentaste enviar o arquivo com `images_file: fs.readFile( __dirname + '/robot_orthographic.jpg', 'utf8')`?

Comment: @Sergio então agora o erro mudou de  400 para 500

Comment: Eu tive que fazer algo parecido com .net core usando form data e adaptando o model: `const files = new FormData()
      files.append('files', this.banners.files)
      files.append('json', JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: Até essa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/387331/como-enviar-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-post-com-arquivos-e-json/387380#387380

Comment: @marconi também não funcionou, ele está reclamando de `parse`: `Error parsing request into form data`

Comment: Não sei como se faz com express. Um dica se você não conseguir sair do problema: Cria uma API para enviar o arquivo e outra pra enviar o json.

Comment: @marconi é também não acredito que seja o express, e sim o axios que não deve estar passando algum parâmetro pois a api retorna `Error parsing request into form data`